# How exactly (and why) can I access all of NumPy through numpy.random?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I was poking through what is available in `numpy.random` after importing

```
from numpy import random
```

with `dir(random)`, and noticed that there was a variable `np` in scope, which appears equivalent to the top-level module, for example

```
In[1]: from numpy import random

In[2]: random.np.fft.fft2
Out[2]: <function numpy.fft.fftpack.fft2>

In[3]: random.np.random.np.fft.np # not the same for fft

AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-a64e04c36c80> in <module>()
----> 1 random.np.random.np.fft.np

AttributeError: module 'numpy.fft' has no attribute 'np'
```

This seems a bit strange to me... or at least not something I've seen before in other Python modules. It looks like I can access everything I could with `import numpy as np` through the `np` variable in `random`.

I wanted to see how it was available to the submodule, so I looked in [`numpy/random/__init__.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/__init__.py) in the source code, and didn't see how it is made available. I also looked in [`numpy/random/info.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/info.py) at `__all__`, but can't find how it is exposed to the module.

How is the top level module made available to `numpy.random`, and is there any motivation for having it available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in `numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx` [line 146](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b94c2b01ff7ef5b8dc44726512cfa232e9054882/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L146) we find:

```
import numpy as np
```

Thus placing the symbol into the module's namespace.  Which, this being python, you can access.  I would imagine that this line is present for the same reason we litter it all over our modules, namely this module needs access to `numpy` functionality.

And backing up one level we find in `/numpy/random/__init__.py` [line 99](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b94c2b01ff7ef5b8dc44726512cfa232e9054882/numpy/random/__init__.py#L99):

```
from .mtrand import *
```

Which closes the circle and gets us access to `np` via the `numpy.random` module.

Comment: You found it! More straightforward than I was making it out to be, thanks!